# $.widget not a function in jquery-ui.min.js, but is in jquery-ui.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm having a bit of trouble tracking down an explanation for this.  I have downloaded a custom version of jquery-ui in order to make use of a switch button.  First, I include the required JS files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery-3.2.1/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/SwitchButton/jquery.switchButton.js"></script>
```

The jquery.switchButton.js file does the following:

```
$.widget("sylightsUI.switchButton", {});
```

When the page loads, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
```

Now, if I use the unminified version of jquery-ui, this renders just fine.  What am I not understanding here?  I have tried downloading the full jquery-ui package and dropping those files in.  Produces the same results.

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: Using a custom version of jquery-ui 1.12.1.

Comment: Would check your path bane and files. Looks like it's not loading. Any errors in console?

Comment: The error in console was the "Uncaught TypeError" above.  For giggles, I tested my code again this morning and it's magically working.  That got me thinking that perhaps an old, bad version of jquery-ui.min.js was cachched in my browser.  I suppose that's what happens when you stare at code for too long during the work week!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears I had a stale version of jquery-ui.min.js cached in the browser.  After that version cleared out and the new one loaded, the error disappeared.